# How to solve 'duplicate symbols for architecture arm64' error?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-error

When I try running my Xcode Project it fails with an error stating that I have duplicate symbols. Below is the way I sovled this error. Hope to help you~

The error info:
[image: Error Info from Xcode]

From the error info I found that WPBuySkinAlertView maybe the duplicate class.So I seach the file in the project.

[image: Duplicate file]

There are two WPBuySkinAlertView files in the project.

So, next time when you come with this error, check your project according to the error info, find the duplicate classes and remove the one.

Comment: i didn't get your issue@Michael Yang

Comment: Also check in root folder too.

Comment: You have added same file 2 time in project remove 1 from them from project target

Answer (score 15):

Select Proiect ===> Target ===> Build phase  ==> Compile source search WPBuySkinAlertView this name you will see 2 file in search result remove one from them

Comment: in my case was a duplicate plugin file

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurred right after installing a new pod, run `pod update`. I suspect that the new pod I installed actually installed some of the same dependencies as a previous pod, so there was a duplicate. `pod update` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, multiple causes can lead to this error. I had 2 files containing `@main` and that is non logical.

In the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) it says:

> Apply this attribute to a structure, class, or enumeration declaration
> to indicate that it contains the top-level entry point for program
> flow.

This was my mistake:

File1.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
...
```

File2.swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my case I had an issue with one of my pods (cocoa pods) and needed to comment it out, re-run it without it and everything seemed fine. I had recently changed the revision for SDWebImage in my Podfile.